# What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?

Tags: java

What's the difference between `getPath()`, `getAbsolutePath()`, and `getCanonicalPath()` in Java?

And when do I use each one?

Comment: Dont forget `Path.toAbsolutePath().normalize()` which is a good middle ground between canonical (real) path and absolute path alone.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

Consider these filenames:

`C:\temp\file.txt` - This is a path, an absolute path, and a canonical path.

`.\file.txt` - This is a path. It's neither an absolute path nor a canonical path.

`C:\temp\myapp\bin\..\\..\file.txt` - This is a path and an absolute path. It's not a canonical path.

A canonical path is always an absolute path.

Converting from a path to a canonical path makes it absolute (usually tack on the current working directory so e.g. `./file.txt` becomes `c:/temp/file.txt`). The  canonical path of a file just "purifies" the path, removing and resolving stuff like `..\` and resolving symlinks (on unixes).

Also note the following example with nio.Paths:

```
String canonical_path_string = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\";
String absolute_path_string = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\..\\";

System.out.println(Paths.get(canonical_path_string).getParent());
System.out.println(Paths.get(absolute_path_string).getParent());
```

While both paths refer to the same location, the output will be quite different:

```
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\drivers
```

Comment: FWIW, it's not a given that `C:\temp\file.txt` is a canonical path - the temp directory might be a file system soft link or hard link (a junction in NTFS), and file.txt might be a soft link.  I don't know if file systems can distinguish hard links to files.

Comment: path does not really consider those issues or existence of any of the components, only the syntax of it.

Comment: It does, canonical path (unlike normalized path) does hit the file system.

Comment: Basically, I can't see a reason why one should use `getAbsolutePath()` instead of `getCanonicalPath()`. It even looks better because the canonical one automatically resolves those `../` parts.

Comment: Don't forget that `getCanonicalPath` throws an `IOException` while `getAbsolutePath` does not, if this is a consideration.

Answer (score 142):

The best way I have found to get a feel for things like this is to try them out:

```
import java.io.File;
public class PathTesting {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        File f = new File("test/.././file.txt");
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Your output will be something like:

```
test\..\.\file.txt
C:\projects\sandbox\trunk\test\..\.\file.txt
C:\projects\sandbox\trunk\file.txt
```

So, `getPath()` gives you the path based on the File object, which may or may not be relative; `getAbsolutePath()` gives you an absolute path to the file; and `getCanonicalPath()` gives you the unique absolute path to the file. Notice that there are a huge number of absolute paths that point to the same file, but only one canonical path.

When to use each? Depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but if you were trying to see if two `Files` are pointing at the same file on disk, you could compare their canonical paths. Just one example.

Comment: It's arguable that Java got it's implementation of an "absolute" path wrong; it really should've removed any relative path elements in an absolute path. The canonical form would then remove any FS links or junctions in the path.

Comment: `but if you were trying to see if two Files are pointing at the same file on disk` How? example please?

Comment: @UnKnown: You'd use the canonical path for that.

Comment: Question... When would you ever want to use the absolute path over the canonical path? Doesn't checking the canonical path "work better" in more scenarios?

Comment: Good example code to explain these terms. Thank you.

Answer (score 87):

In short:

- `getPath()` gets the path string that the `File` object was constructed with, and it may be relative current directory.
- `getAbsolutePath()` gets the path string after resolving it against the current directory if it's relative, resulting in a fully qualified path.
- `getCanonicalPath()` gets the path string after resolving any relative path against current directory, and removes any relative pathing (`.` and `..`), and any file system links to return a path which the file system considers the canonical means to reference the file system object to which it points.

Also, each of these has a File equivalent which returns the corresponding `File` object.

Note that IMO, Java got the implementation of an "absolute" path wrong; it really should remove any relative path elements in an absolute path. The canonical form would then remove any FS links or junctions in the path.

Comment: Only explanation I found to be clear as ice. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

`getPath()` returns the path used to create the `File` object. This return value is not changed based on the location it is run (results below are for windows, separators are obviously different elsewhere)

```
File f1 = new File("/some/path");
String path = f1.getPath(); // will return "\some\path"

File dir = new File("/basedir");
File f2 = new File(dir, "/some/path");
path = f2.getPath(); // will return "\basedir\some\path"

File f3 = new File("./some/path");
path = f3.getPath(); // will return ".\some\path"
```

`getAbsolutePath()` will resolve the path based on the execution location or drive. So if run from `c:\test`:

```
path = f1.getAbsolutePath(); // will return "c:\some\path"
path = f2.getAbsolutePath(); // will return "c:\basedir\some\path"
path = f3.getAbsolutePath(); // will return "c:\test\.\basedir\some\path"
```

`getCanonicalPath()` is system dependent. It will resolve the unique location the path represents. So if you have any "."s in the path they will typically be removed.

As to when to use them. It depends on what you are trying to achieve. `getPath()` is useful for portability. `getAbsolutePath()` is useful to find the file system location, and `getCanonicalPath()` is particularly useful to check if two files are the same.

Comment: can you give me any example of this? `getCanonicalPath() is particularly useful to check if two files are the same.`

Comment: So basically if you want your code to work on multiple operating systems you should just use getCanonicalPath() ??

Answer (score 23):

The big thing to get your head around is that the `File` class tries to represent a view of what Sun like to call "hierarchical pathnames" (basically a path like `c:/foo.txt` or `/usr/muggins`). This is why you create files in terms of paths. The operations you are describing are all operations upon this "pathname".

- `getPath()` fetches the path that the File was created with (`../foo.txt`)
- `getAbsolutePath()` fetches the path that the File was created with, but includes information about the current directory if the path is relative (`/usr/bobstuff/../foo.txt`)
- `getCanonicalPath()` **attempts** to fetch a unique representation of the absolute path to the file. This eliminates indirection from ".." and "." references (`/usr/foo.txt`).

Note I say **attempts** - in forming a Canonical Path, the VM can throw an `IOException`. This usually occurs because it is performing some filesystem operations, any one of which could fail.

Answer (score 3):

I find I rarely have need to use `getCanonicalPath()` but, if given a File with a filename that is in DOS 8.3 format on Windows, such as the `java.io.tmpdir` System property returns, then this method will return the "full" filename.