# What is the different between getAbsolutePath and getCanonicalPath

Tags: java, file

Java Newbie question : what is the different between getAbsolutePath() and getcanonicalPath() in file class. I can't get the meaning from the documents. in below code, their output are the same.

```
public class copyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       File inputFile = new File("/home/kit.ho/");
       System.out.println("get AbsolutePath");
       System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
       System.out.println("get CanonicalPath");
       System.out.println(inputFile.getCanonicalPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: [Avajava](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-a-files-path-absolute-path-and-canonical-path.html) has a fairly good explanation of the differences...

Comment: absoulet path gives the entire path for example /user/username/nameoffolder/txt while conical path is like nameoffolder/txt (notice there is no / before nameoffolder) hope that helps

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose `/home` was actually a symbolic link to `/usr/home`. Then `getAbsolutePath` would still return `/home/kit.ho/` whereas `getCanonicalPath` would resolve the symlink and return `/usr/home/kit.ho/`.

Comment: Similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath