# what's the difference between canonicalpath and absolutepath?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)

Any difference between those two?

canonicalpath and absolutepath?

If having difference, a real world example will be needed.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099370/985026
(Question asked was What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The difference is that there is only one canonical path to a file<sup>[1]</sup>, while there can be many absolute paths to a file (depending on the system). For instance, on a Unix system, `/usr/local/../bin` is the same as `/usr/bin`. `getCanonicalPath()` resolves those ambiguities and returns the (unique) canonical path. So if the current directory was `/usr/local`, then:

```
File file = new File("../bin");
System.out.println(file.getPath());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

would print:

> ../bin
> /usr/local/../bin
> /usr/bin

Per Voo's suggestion: on Unix systems, `getCanonicalPath()` will also resolve symbolic links if the symbolic link exists. Hard links are treated like normal files (which is basically what they are). Note, however, that a file need not exist for these methods to succeed.

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Well, not quite. As @Tom Hale points out in a comment, if the file system supports hard-linked directories, there may be multiple canonical paths to a given file.</sub>

Comment: Maybe a quick word about sym- and hardlinks would help too.

Comment: If your system supports hard-linking directories, there may be more than one canonical path.

Comment: @TomHale - That's true; hadn't thought about that. However, there should still be only one canonical path for any particular path defined by a `File` object.

Comment: what do you think if I am developing an application for production and on production, UNIX based server is running should I use a canonical path or absolute path. Asking in terms of which will be best approach

Comment: @UmarTahir - It depends on why you need the path string. It often makes no difference to functionality; if it does, then of course use the one that is required for proper function. I believe (without having done the research to back this up) that `getCanonicalPath()` is a bit more expensive to evaluate than `getAbsolutePath()`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a **canonical** path.

> C:/files/foo.txt

Here are **absolute** paths

- C:/files/FOO.TXT
- C:/files/FOO.txt
- C:/files/foo.TXT
- C:/FILES/FOO.TXT

A canonical path is an *absolute unique path* to the file.
A file can have only one canonical path and many absolute paths.

A file can have only have one canonical path which is the file path of the file.
A file can have many absolute paths to the file.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many absolute paths to a file. However there can only be one canonical path to a file. [Read this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-relative-and-canonical-path-of-file-or-directory/60)

Comment: Consider improving this answer to contain more than just a link. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers