# How to get path to the application's files folder which is situated in sdcard0?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for developing my application. I saw a lot of answers but didn't find something which can help me. How can I get the path to the application's files folder which is situated in sdcard0? I want to get something like that: `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/[MyApplication]/files`.

I did the following:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

It gives me `"/data/data/App1.Droid/files"` but it is not I'm looking for.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, maybe you could try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: use `getCanonicalPath()`. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488754/whats-the-difference-between-canonicalpath-and-absolutepath)  accpet my comment as answer! ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
// this for your application directory 
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)



// for external storage 
File path = Android.OS.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

[Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory/p/System.String/)

Update

Note : to call `System.Environment` => you need to be in droid application cant be called in PCl

to call `Android.OS.Environment`  => you need to reference mono.android in your PCl or called in direct in your droid application

Comment: I use Xamarin framework and C# language. Unfortunately, there is no API which provides your method. You can see this link https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Environment/ This part of code `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("files");` gives me `"/storage/sdcard0/files"`, but I need my application folder also.

Comment: if you call this method in your droid application it will work just fine , but if you called in PCl (first you cant call System.Environment , Second you need reference mono android to call Android.OS.Environment )