# Different path to the bluetooth folder on different devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

My app need to transfer some files from the bluetooth folder, to another folder created by my application. The problem is that the bluetooth folder is located at different paths on different devices. On my `Samsung galaxy S3` the path is `/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth` and when I test the application on a `Samsung galaxy S2` I can't even **find** the bluetooth folder! Is there anyway I can search for, or get the bluetooth folder programmatically in Java?

This is the code where I navigate me to the Bluetooth folder on my Samsung S3:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String bluetoothFile = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bluetooth";
File bluetoothFolder = new File(bluetoothFile);
```

And using this `get` method to get the path to my bluetooth folder

```
public File getBluetoothFolder() {
    return bluetoothFolder;
}
```

This is just for the Samsung S3, but when I upload the app to another phone, this will only result in a `NullPointerException` because the bluetooth folder isn't located at `/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth`

Comment: upload your code for more clarification, please

Comment: which different phone you are using ?

Comment: Samsung S3 and S2 + HTC Desire. It shouldn't matter, because the app should run on every phone with android 2.2 and above.

Comment: ok, in those phones, where is bluetooth folder is located ?

Comment: If you read my post, it should explain it all! It doesnt matter where the folder is, but is there a universal way to find the path of the bluetooth folder, independent of the mobile manufacture?

Comment: you would be surprise to know that, i am working same kind of situation at present.

Comment: Don't use getAbsolutePath() method, instead try this `String bluetoothFile = sdcard.getPath() + "/Bluetooth";`

Comment: Nope, but after some time I found out that the Galaxy S2 and S3 creates a bluetooth folder at the same place, but the S3 with a capital B and S2 with a lowercase b...

Comment: see this `http://stackoverflow.com/q/1099300/996493`