# get a file path

Tags: java, file

Is there a way to get the full path for a file exists on the computer ? 
For example , I want to get the full path for a file in a folder on desktop

I tried using :

```
  File f = new File("help.chm");

  String f2=f.getAbsolutePath();
  f3=f3.replaceAll("\\\\","/" );
  System.out.println("Path:"+f3);
```

but it gave me the path of the project like this:

> C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/help.chm

although the file is not located there .

Comment: You are looking for `getCanonicalPath()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath By the way, the file is not check on existance.

Comment: @tuergeist : but the file exists

Comment: First you need to find the file, before you can get it's path. For your specific example you can get the desktop path using: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";` then you can search through folders on your desktop for a matching file name.
Read here to learn how to search for files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Comment: you can get what you can't get the absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other answers do not cover your question, here is my comment:

To get a file's path, you first need to tell your java program where it is or how to find it.

For your specific example you can get the desktop path using: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";` then you can search through folders on your desktop for a matching file name.

Read here to learn how to search for files: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `file` using `new File("filename")` which is the `relative path`, you cannot get the absolute path of the file using `file.getAbsolutePath()`, because the relative path is build according to the default user home directory or the JVM path.

Take a look at [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html): -

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute
>   or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other
>   information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes.
>
> A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of
>   information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in
>   the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the
>   current user directory. This directory is named by the system property
>   user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual
>   machine was invoked.

So, to get the `absolute path` for this case, you would actually have to write the path yourself. Get the `absolute path` till the directory where you saved the `file`, and append the `file name` to it.

Answer (score 0):

A `File` is a representation of a file *path*, not necessarily an existent file on disk - ie the file doesn't have to exist on disk for a `File` object to be not `null`.

That's why there's the `File.exists()` method.

Comment: ok , but I want to get the correct path of the file , which is located on  the desktop

Answer (score 0):

The path "help.chm" will be relative to the directory from which you started the JVM, which in your case appears to be `C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/`

To get a path to the desktop, you need to use the absolute path of the desktop directory in Windows, which will be something along the lines of `C:/Users/toshiba/Desktop/help.chm`

Comment: do you mean that I have to write the path ??

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to read the file from (default folder)

```
C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/
```

File doesn't exist but the would-be-file's path will be

```
C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/
```

If you read the file from where it really is:

File f = new File("C:/Users/toshiba/Desktop/help.chm");

You will see that `exists()` returns true.

```
 System.out.println(f.exists());
```

Then:

```
  String f2=f.getCanonicalPath();
```