# What file path format to use for connecting to derby database?

Tags: java, derby

From the [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp40350.html) I do not really get what I have to specify when connecting to a derby database, given the path to the database as `java.io.File`.

What has to be `path` in the following code?

```
File dbDirectory;

// ...

String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + path
                + ";create=true");
```

Surely, it should be system independent.
Do I use one of the following?

- `dbDirectory.getAbsolutePath()`
- `dbDirectory.getCanonicalPath()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that either getAbsolutePath or getCanonicalPath will work. In fact, you can also provide a relative path, so long as the relative path you specify is relative to the derby.system.home setting.

This question has some useful information about the differences between the three paths: [What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)

Derby is quite tolerant of different path settings, and will generally handle any of these.

If I had a choice, however, I would use getCanonicalPath, as it's the "cleanest" of the paths, and also is least likely to be affected by unexpected re-setting of derby.system.home.

**However**, if you are **intending** to build your application in such a way that it can be moved from location to location on the different computers, and use its database regardless, you may find it more convenient to use a relative path, because then your application becomes more "self contained" and you don't have to deal with differences in drive mappings,  home directory folder name differences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of derby connection strings:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102

Full documentation for derby connection strings:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html

Comment: But that´s the page I linked to and the examples are not enough...
I need to know how to get from the `File` object to the path String derby wants.

Comment: So you want people to read the documentation for you and do it for you? The documentation states that if the database file is not n the class path you specify the full path. What more do you need?

Comment: I read the documentation, but I asked in which **format** the path has to be. For me, "full path" is not quite clear, because there are different formats to represent a file´s path and it´s also system dependent.