# Detect a File Extension in Java

Tags: java, file, ends-with

I'm trying to detect if the file that I am opening is a HTML file.

I have already tried this:

```
try {
   String file = fileName.getCanonicalPath();

   if (file.endsWith(".htm") | file.endsWith(".html")) {

   }

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

But the `file.endsWith();` doesn't seem to be detecting anything. The `fileName` is the file that I'm opening. Let me know if I have to post the code that I use to open the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need the canonical path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line looks suspect:

```
if (file.endsWith(".htm") | file.endsWith(".html")) {
```

The `|` operator is the bitwise-OR operator.  You need the logical-OR operator, `||`.

**EDIT**

Adding what @MadProgrammer suggessted in a comment:

Call `toLowerCase()` on the filename to account for the possibility that the file ends in `.HTM` or `.HTML`.

Comment: I'd also add `file.toLowerCase().endsWith` to ensure that you don't run into case comparison issues +1 none the less

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Good point, it could be ".HTM" for all we know.

Comment: -1, the bitwise `|` works fine, it just doesn't have the short circuit feature.

Comment: How would this solve the issue? Using `|` makes the second boolean expression evaluated regardless what the first expression returns.

Comment: It works. I over-thought it. Although, I did move it around in my code. I'm not sure what caused it to work, but I'll accept your answer nonetheless.

Comment: @jlordo, I never expected `|` to work here.  But I just tested `true | false` and `true & false` and they work as would be expected.  I still think that `||` should be used here.

Comment: @rgettman: I agree that using `a || b` is to be preferred over `a | b` unless you really need `a` _and_ `b` evaluated. But this won't solve OPs problem at all...

Answer (score 2):

You might have a case issue here as well. As @rgettman points out you probably need a logical or in there too

```
if (file.toLowerCase().endsWith(".htm") || file.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html")) {
```