# The third party application does not read my pdf file

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am new in android just wanna know whats wrong with my code it doesn't read my pdf file when i selected from my list.
here is my code:

```
public class ChoosefileActivity extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root;
private TextView myPath;
public final static String loc = "com.example.mypdfviewer.loc";
    private String dirPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choosefile);

    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        getDir(root);
    }

private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
    myPath.setText(dirPath); 
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());    
    }
    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
        path.add(file.getPath());
        if(file.isDirectory()){
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
    }
    else
    {
        item.add(file.getName());
    }
    }   
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
        {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));
        }
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        }   
        }
        else 
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("Open: " + "[" + file.getName() + "]")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int v) 
                {   

                File file = new File(**dirPath**);
                                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
                }) 
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
                }).show();
                }
                }
            }
```

it shows and error dialog that it could not read the file 
but when i use the hardcoded path, like this:

```
File file = new File("**/mnt/sdcard/pdf_File/another.pdf**");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

this code can show in any application that can read pdf. i just use this just to check if theres any problem with the file, but i found out that i think it is in my code. what i need is not the hardcoded path. kindly help me please.

Comment: Why don't you print the path you've concatenated, just before you access the .pdf file. Log it to see if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

How are you constructing the `**dirPath**` used on the `new File()` ?

If the hardcoded path is working but the other one is not, my guess is that path maybe is wrong. Try putting an Log.d and verify what is on `**dirPath**`

Did you tried using the getAbsolutePath instead of getPath ?

See this thread, maybe can help you - [What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)