# Get size and name of selected file in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

Good evening all, I was wondering what syntax I would use to get the size (mb) and the name of the selected file in my JFileChooser.

```
JFileChooser filedlg = new JFileChooser();
    filedlg.showOpenDialog(null);
    textField.setText(//File's name);
    textField_1.setText(//File's size);
```

What would I use to replace the comments?  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   JFileChooser filedlg = new JFileChooser();
    filedlg.showOpenDialog(null);
    File selected = filedlg.getSelectedFile();
    textField.setText(selected.getName());
    textField_1.setText(selected.length());

    String fullName = selected.getAbsolutePath();
```

Also, the .length() gives size in bytes, so you will have to transform it to whatever you want after.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: How do I get file path?  Sorry, should have asked in original post ;)

Comment: Edited my answer, check it again.

Comment: @TheCodingTraceur To get the absolute path of the file:  `selected.getCanonicalPath()`.

Comment: absolutePath has always worked for me, but read more here about which to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath

Comment: Thanks both of you, I'll experiment with the 2 of them @YasmaniLlanes

Comment: textField_1.setText(selected.length()); Does not work because .setText needs a string.