# What are the differences between Path.toRealPath() and Path.toAbsolutePath()?

Tags: java, java-11

I'd like to understand what are the differences between `Path.toRealPath()` and `Path.toAbsolutePath()`.

```java
Path path = Path.of("/Users/user/projects/../.zprofile");
System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath()); // Prints /Users/user/projects/../.zprofile
System.out.println(path.toRealPath()); // Prints /Users/user/.zprofile
```

I read that `toRealPath` does remove redundant characters that `toAbsolutePath` doesn't, and also check for the real existence of the file (example above).
However, besides those ones, are there any other differences I should be aware of? And how do those apply in practice?

Comment: Have you read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.htm) for those two methods?  They will explain what they do, and the differences will be self-evident.

Comment: Yes, but I found them at some level generic, I'd like to have some practical examples.

Comment: Read ["Difference between getCanonicalPath and toRealPath"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920623/difference-between-getcanonicalpath-and-torealpath). There's a lot of eamples there. This and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) will give you all the information you need. In general what `toRealPath` does is mostly iplementation-dependent. So there are really not many guarantees about what this method does in general. You'd have to consider this question in terms of a concrete implementation (Windows/Linux, filesystem type etc).

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation for `toRealPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath(java.nio.file.LinkOption...)):

> The precise definition of this method is implementation dependent but in general it derives from this path, an absolute path that locates the same file as this path, but with name elements that represent the actual name of the directories and the file. For example, where filename comparisons on a file system are case insensitive then the name elements represent the names in their actual case. Additionally, the resulting path has redundant name elements removed.
>
> If this path is relative then its absolute path is first obtained, as if by invoking the toAbsolutePath method.
>
> The options array may be used to indicate how symbolic links are handled. By default, symbolic links are resolved to their final target. If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then this method does not resolve symbolic links. Some implementations allow special names such as ".." to refer to the parent directory. When deriving the real path, and a ".." (or equivalent) is preceded by a non-".." name then an implementation will typically cause both names to be removed. When not resolving symbolic links and the preceding name is a symbolic link then the names are only removed if it guaranteed that the resulting path will locate the same file as this path.

So that tells us a few things about `toRealPath`:

- On a case-insensitive file system, if the actual path contains the name `Example` and the path string you're using contains `example` instead, `toRealPath` will give you `Example` — the real name — instead of `example`.
- Redundant parts of the path are removed.
- On a file system with symbolic links, if you don't specify the `NOFOLLOW_LINKS` option, symbolic links will be followed and the real path (without links) will be returned.

Contrast with [`toAbsolutePath`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath()), which just resolves a relative path without necessarily doing that kind of additional processing.

In both cases, though, a fair bit of what they do is described as implementation-dependent.