# Java - Get final "destination" of a file

Tags: java, file

I was wondering, how can I find the final destination of a file?

For example, if I write this path:

```
C:\JavaDir\2ndDir\file.txt
```

The path would be simple, but if I type, for example:

```
C:\JavaDir\2ndDir\3rdDir\..\file.txt
```

Now, I can see that the destination would be ...\2ndDir\file.txt, but how can I run a command to check the destination?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath) may help, java.io.File.getCanonicalPath() returns what your requirement is, I think

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: File.getCanonicalPath() worked just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the *canonical* path, which is unique for every single file.  You basically just need to create a File object and run [the getCanonicalPath() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) to get what you want.

```
File f = new File(yourPath);
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

...checking for exceptions, yada yada.