# getCanonicalPath different from getAbsolutePath - adding "/private"

Tags: java, scala

As I understand the different [getPath,getAbsolutePath and getCanonicalPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath) what I don't understand why does absolute path is different from Canonical path - in the Canonical path I see `/private` prefix which doesn't exist in absolute path

I run the below code in scala

```
object ScalaDemo {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val dir = Files.createTempDirectory("test").toFile

      println("dir.getPath:" + dir.getPath)
      println("dir.getAbsolutePath:" + dir.getAbsolutePath)
      println("dir.getCanonicalPath:" + dir.getCanonicalPath)
   }
}
```

I got this output:

```
dir.getPath:/var/folders/fq/8q8jpphd2qb2_07p4h2kzn0m0000gn/T/test3084029786797422592
dir.getAbsolutePath:/var/folders/fq/8q8jpphd2qb2_07p4h2kzn0m0000gn/T/test3084029786797422592
dir.getCanonicalPath:/private/var/folders/fq/8q8jpphd2qb2_07p4h2kzn0m0000gn/T/test3084029786797422592
```

Can see that the Canonical path have `/private` prefix - Why is that?

I also run `ls -al` on the absolute path output to see if there is symlink but didn't find any. I'm using mac with scala 2.9.1

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+argument+lengths+differ#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+getCanonicalPath+getAbsolutePath)

Comment: Do `ls -l /var`, `/var` refers to `private/var`. like luk2302 is saying

Comment: @luk2302 you are so right! I didn't think to check the root folder (`/var`) - Thanks

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I add this link in the question and it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not run `ls -al` on the final path. If you were looking for a symlink you would have to step from the first folder downwards to the file. Luckily this process is quickly over since `ls -la /` yields amongst others:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel     11 Jan 11 14:16 var -> private/var
```

Meaning it is in fact a symlink and therefore the canonical paths "expands" the link.