# How can I access absolute path in Gradle Copy-task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am logging in Copy task like:

```
[...]
from ("some/source/") {
  include "*.*"
  into "some/destination"
        
  eachFile { file ->
    logger.info("Copied ${file.sourcePath} -> ${file.path}" )
  }
}
```

`file.sourcePath` will just give me the files name. How can I get the absolute path? I am not getting warm with Gradle documentation yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)

Comment: Not really. If I try `file.getCanonicalPath()` I get Execution failed for task ':updatelighttestme'.
> Could not find method getCanonicalPath() for arguments [] on file 'C:\my\path\backup_db.bat' of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails_Decorated.

Comment: I am using Gradle 5.6.4 btw.